# Creating a video from the visible window or view

Tags: iphone, video, camera, avfoundation

I have requirement to record video from the visible view.i,e not form camera. like in TalkingTom application. Can any suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can take screenshot (using [UIGetScreenImage](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html)) and store the images into an array.

Then convert it into video using mpeg coder.