# How to make capture screen and make video in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one iphone application in which there is some animation.I want to make video of animation using screen capture through programming.

Is it possible ?

Please help me for this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html) to capture screen image

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335886/creating-a-video-from-the-visible-window-or-view/4337041#4337041

Comment: Be careful on using `UIGetScreenImage()` as its usage is not allowed anymore.

Comment: Hope the tutorial [here](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673) provides all your needs...